# I am using React Context and would like to get confirmed my structure

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

It is my first application using react context with hooks instead of react-redux and would like to get help of the structure of the application.
(I'm NOT using react-redux or redux-saga libraries.)

- Context

```
const AppContext = createContext({
  client,
  user,
});
```

- One of actions example

```
export const userActions = (state, dispatch) => {
  function getUsers() {
    dispatch({ type: types.GET_USERS });
    axios
      .get("api address")
      .then(function(response) {
        dispatch({ type: types.GOT_USERS, payload: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
      });
  }
  return {
    getUsers,
  };
};
```

- Reducer (index.js): I used combineReducer function code from the redux library

```
const AppReducer = combineReducers({
  client: clientReducer,
  user: userReducer,
});
```

- Root.js

```
import React, { useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import AppContext from "./context";
import AppReducer from "./reducers";
import { clientActions } from "./actions/clientActions";
import { userActions } from "./actions/userActions";
import App from "./App";

const Root = () => {
  const initialState = useContext(AppContext);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);
  const clientDispatch = clientActions(state, dispatch);
  const userDispatch = userActions(state, dispatch);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        clientState: state.client,
        userState: state.user,
        clientDispatch,
        userDispatch,
      }}
    >
      <App />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Root;
```

So, whenever the component wants to access the context store or dispatch an action, this is how I do from the component :

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import ListMenu from "../common/ListMenu";
import List from "./List";
import AppContext from "../../context";
import Frame from "../common/Frame";

const Example = props => {
  const { match, history } = props;
  const { userState, userDispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

  // Push to user detail route /user/userId
  const selectUserList = userId => {
    history.push(`/user/${userId}`);
    userDispatch.clearTabValue(true);
  };

  return (
    <Frame>
      <ListMenu
        dataList={userState.users}
        selectDataList={selectUserList}
      />
      <List />
    </Frame>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

The problem I faced now is that whenever I dispatch an action or try to access to the context store, the all components are re-rendered since the context provider is wrapping entire app.

I was wondering how to fix this entire re-rendering issue (if it is possible to still use my action/reducer folder structure).

Also, I'm fetching data from the action, but I would like to separate this from the action file as well like how we do on redux-saga structure. I was wondering if anybody know how to separate this without using redux/redux-saga.

Thanks and please let me know if you need any code/file to check.

Comment: Please show code of some component that use context to extract data from store

Comment: @Fyodor Hi Fyodor, thanks for the comment. I added on the last code section. You can see dispatch from userDispatch.clearTabValue(true); and use state from dataList={userState.users}.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this re-rendering issue and I found this info on the official website:
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats
May it will help you too

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am currently sending reducers/actions and state to context provider and to follow the solution you shared, I have to store those to the state and it didn't work well :( What do you think was wrong on my approach?

Answer (score 0):

This effect (updating components on context update) is described in [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

> A component calling useContext will always re-render when the context value changes. If re-rendering the component is expensive, you can optimize it by using memoization

Possible solutions to this also [described](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156#issuecomment-474590693)

I see universal solution is to `useMemo`

For example

```
const Example = props => {
    const { match, history } = props;
    const { userState, userDispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

    // Push to user detail route /user/userId
    const selectUserList = userId => {
        history.push(`/user/${userId}`);
        userDispatch.clearTabValue(true);
    };
    const users = userState.users; 

    return useMemo(() => {
        return <Frame>
            <ListMenu
                dataList={users}
                selectDataList={selectUserList}
            />
            <List />
        </Frame>
    }, [users, selectUserList]);  // Here are variables that component depends on
};
```

I also may recommend you to completly switch to Redux. You're almost there with using `combineReducers` and `dispatch`. React-redux now exposes [`useDispatch` and  `useSelector` hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks), so you can make your code very close to what you're doing now (replace `useContext` with `useSelector` and `useReducer` with `useDispatch`. It will require minor changes to arguments)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Fyodor. I got your point of using Redux, but if I stay with non-redux, do you think it is correct way to send the state/reducers/actions to context provider? What do you think is the one which triggers unnecessary re-rendering?

Comment: If staying non-redux, you may still follow general riles of Redux. (1) Redux saves`state` and `dispatch` in store. So you can do, (2) Action creators in Redux live separately from dispatch, so you may also extract action creators from context. (3) React-redux `connect `compare state so rendering happens only when state changed. So you can do with `useMemo`